# Google Cloud SSL/HTTPS Load Balancer

Tags: ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set an HTTP load balancer with SSL.
I have two files - certificate.pem and unencryptedkey.pem.

But the UI of google asks for three fields:

- Public key certificate,
- Certificate chain,
- Private key

What goes where and where do I get the third one?

I managed to use only 2 but the browser asks for permission and that is wrong.

Comment: There is a feature request at Google Cloud https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62049778 , you may upvote/star it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you buy the SSL certificate you should get some more files. In my case, I got  a .ca file (certificate chain), a .crt file (the certificate), a .csr file (the request), and a .key file (your private key)

You need

- public key => the crt file
- certificate chain => your ca file(s concatenated)
- private key => your .key

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have created the certificates, i.e. you haven't purchased them from some certificate authority. With self-signed certificates browser warns you, since certificate validity can't be verified from a certificate authority.

If this is the case, you should do some learning regarding certificates and how they work.